# Lattices from quaternion algebras (MAGMA software)

Tags: lattice-theory, division-algebras, magma, quaternion-algebras

I am studying the paper "[Lattice Packing from Quaternion Algebras](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/196240/1/B32_014.pdf)" from 2012 about the construction of ideal lattices.

In Section 3.3 the authors construct very interesting examples of lattices using quaternion algebras over number fields. In Example 3.3, they choose an ideal of the maximal quaternion order, but I could not understand how to do this using Magma (or even other software). I am really puzzled about how to get this ideal (with N (N (I)) = 7).

I understand the construction and the way it happens, but I do not understand how I can select an ideal as they do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The paper gives generators for the lattice, and my recollection is that Magma will give you the ideal generated by a set of elements in a quaternion algebra.  Are you saying you can't get the ideal function to work?

Comment: Yes, Magma gives the ideal generated by a set in a quaternion algebra. My question is how to find an ideal with a given norm. In Example 3.3 they select an ideal of a maximal quaternion order such that $N(N(I)) = 7$. I'm confused about how to obtain that using Magma (or another software) or if there is some theoretical result that leads me to obtain such ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Given an order $O$ in a quaternion algebra $B$ over a number field $K$, I believe you want to construct an integral ideal $I$ in $O$ with some given norm $n$ (an ideal in $K$).  I don't believe Magma has any built-in function to do this directly, but you should be able to do this in one of the following ways using various built-in Magma commands:

(1) If $n$ is principal and $N(O)= \mathfrak o_K$, look for an element $\alpha$ of norm $n$ in $B$.  If you find one, then you can take $I=\alpha O$.

(2) In general, given a (pseudo)basis for $O$, construct all "small" linear combinations whose norms lie in $n$.  Then construct the ideal generated these elements and compute the norm.  If the norm is $n$, you're done.  Otherwise, try adding more linear combinations to the ideal.